# Printing the form submitted by User

Tags: php, opencart

I recently setup a website on OpenCart. The site is an online shop (An online Restaurant) which helps users to order online or place order on the website. 
Now here's the scenario! sometimes we don't look back at our admin panel and we miss few of our orders. What i need to know is if there is some sort of solution like if a person places an order and after submitting the order we get the print out automatically?

Comment: Printout might be difficult, but youo can get an email copy of the order: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18720&filter_search=email%20order

Comment: It's quite simple even to send email to the restaurant operator so he can open up his email and can search. But the problem is print solution so there shouldn't be any order missed.

Comment: In order to print he is going to need an Internet-ready printer. There are a lot of low cost ones. HP has several. HP comes with a cloud service where you can direct emails to and have them print. Worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll surely look into this one option as this seems really worth. Thank you

Comment: Found this for you. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8907&filter_search=auto%20print%20order

Comment: Since this is specific to opencart, you may want to try http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart